# Converting floating point numbers to integers, rounding to 2 decimals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, int

What's the best way to perform the following conversions in JavaScript? I have currencies stored as floats that I want rounded and converted to integers.

`1501.0099999999999909` -> `150101`

`12.00000000000001` -> `1200`

Comment: Are you just doing `Math.round(num * 100)`

Comment: I hadn't picked a method, but that surely seems the simplest. Are there any additional accuracy drawbacks here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `toFixed` method off a Number combined with `parseFloat`.

Eg,

```
var number = 1501.0099999999999909;
var truncated = parseFloat(number.toFixed(5));
console.log(truncated);
```

`toFixed` takes in the number of decimal points it should be truncated to.

To get the output you need, you would only need `toFixed(2)' and multiple the result by 100.

Eg,

```
var number = 1501.0099999999999909;
var truncated = parseFloat(number.toFixed(2)) * 100;
console.log(truncated);
```

Comment: And do you recommend just multiplying that by 100?